# Powershell IIS Log analasys

Tags: iis-7.5, powershell-2.0

I almost have this Powershell script completed but I am stuck at the last part and could really use some help with the final step.  Below is my PS Script that I have written so far

```
$t1 =(get-date).AddMinutes(-10)
$t2 =$t1.ToUniversalTime().ToString("HH:mm:ss")
$IISLogPath = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\"+"u_ex"+(get-date).ToString("yyMMdd")+".log" 
$IISLogFileRaw = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($IISLogPath) 
$headers = $IISLogFileRaw[3].split(" ") 
$headers = $headers | where {$_ -ne "#Fields:"}
$IISLogFileCSV = Import-Csv -Delimiter " " -Header $headers -Path $IISLogPath
$IISLogFileCSV = $IISLogFileCSV | where {$_.date -notlike "#*"}
$timeTaken = $IISLogFileCSV | where {$_.("cs-uri-stem") -eq '/Login.aspx' -AND $_.("time") -gt '$t2' } | Format-Table time,s-ip
```

So basically it looks at the current days IIS Log and filters when a user gets to the login page for the past 10 minutes.  The part that I am stuck at is I want to be emailed When an IP hits it more than 10 times within that 10 minutes (basically to be alerted when brute force attacks are happening).  I have the email part of the code written just need the portion that says when the s-ip hits /login.aspx greater than 10 times. Also in my "test box" I have altered `$t2` and `$IISLogPath` to be the following

```
$t2 = 20:00:00
$IISLogPath = C:\test\log.log
```

Below is my example Log file:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2012-06-27 15:05:24
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2012-06-27 20:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 20:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 20:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 20:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
2012-06-27 21:32:35 ::1 GET /Login.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:13.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/13.0.1 500 0 0 24240
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little tinkering with the script, I have found the solution. Below is the whole script

```
$t1 =(get-date).AddMinutes(-10)
$t2 =$t1.ToUniversalTime().ToString("HH:mm:ss")
$IISLogPath = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\"+"u_ex"+(get-date).ToString("yyMMdd")+".log" 
$IISLogFileRaw = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($IISLogPath) 
$headers = $headers | where {$_ -ne "#Fields:"} 
$IISLogFileCSV = Import-Csv -Delimiter " " -Header $headers -Path $IISLogPath 
$IISLogFileCSV = $IISLogFileCSV | where {$_.date -notlike "#*"} 
$timeTaken = ($IISLogFileCSV | where {$_.("cs-uri-stem") -eq '/Login.aspx' -AND $_.("time") -gt '$t2' -AND $_.("cs-method") -eq 'Get'}).count  
$count = $timeTaken
if($count -ge 8)
{
 Send-MailMessage -From from@domain.com -To to@domain.com -Subject "IIS Alert" -BodyAsHtml "Email body goes here" -Attachments $IISLogPath  -SmtpServer ip.add.re.ss
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You ought to be using [Microsoft LogParser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx) for most of the heavy lifting in parsing/querying your logfiles. It'll save you a lot of grief, and probably be faster to boot.

You can wrap it with PowerShell to parse the results of your queries.

Comment: True but I thought Microsoft didnt support it on a Server 2008 platform.  Also since im not going to be sitting running this script every 10 minutes (but the task scheduler is)  wouldnt it make more sense to strictly use powershell and not import other programs into it to? If i was sitting at the server on the other hand I would of so chose LP :)

Comment: @jladd - FYI, I am on Windows Server 2012 and am using [LogParser 2.2 + Log Parser Studio](http://blogs.technet.com/b/karywa/archive/tags/log+parser+studio/default.aspx) to parse IIS logs as we speak.  It has an "Export to PowerShell" feature.